# Position Sticky not work when "enable touch simulation" is turned on

Tags: css, sass, styling, sticky

I have some annoying issues with CSS (or dev tools?). I created a sidebar with position: sticky and it's working great until I turn on touch simulation in Firefox dev tools. Then the sidebar is not following the screen, it's just still in the same place as with position: relative. How to fix it?

````
.SidePanel__container {
    height: 89vh;

    @include respond-to("xs") {
        width: 40px;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
    }

    @include respond-to("lg") {
        width: 250px;
        position: relative;
    }
}```
````

Comment: Can you show the full code to make a [mre] ?